# MongoDB reverse key-value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

say I have a collection called `A` whose structure is as follows:

```
{
    A_id: a1,
    A_list:
    {[
      {B_id: b1, B_boolean: true},
      {B_id: b2, B_boolean: false},
      {B_id: b3, B_boolean: true},
      ...
    ]}
},
{
    A_id: a2,
    A_list:
    {[
      {B_id: b1, B_boolean: true},
      {B_id: b4, B_boolean: true},
      ...
    ]}
},
...
```

Basically, there's a mapping from `A_id` to `B_id`
Now I want to create a collection `B` out of the data in `A` showing a reversed mapping from `B_id` to `A_id`(I only care about the relation between `B_id` and `A_id`). I expect `B` to be like:

```
{
    B_id: b1,
    B_list:
    {[A_id: a1, A_id: a2]}

},
{
    B_id: b2,
    B_list:
    {[A_id: a1]}

},
{
    B_id: b3,
    B_list:
    {[A_id: a1]}

},
...
```

I'm quite new to MongoDB. Could anyone please let me know how to write this query? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your collection A example, the documents can not have a sub-document without a key field. You would need a key name, for example `{A_id:"ai", FOOBAR: [{B_id:"b1"}, {B_id:"b2"}]}`. Could you re-clarify your example document please ?

Comment: I've fixed it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by aggregation pipeline in MongoDB, with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator, below is the MongoDB query and working example, please check

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$A_list"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        B_id: "$A_list.B_id"
      },
      "B_list": {
        "$push": {
          A_id: "$A_id"
        }
      },

    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      B_id: "$_id.B_id",
      B_list: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Working example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/lJxis7fUrDr